# .is(':even') does not work with a variable selector?

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

I am using jQuery to check if an element is **odd** or **even**:

```
 $("#map183").parent().is(':even');
```

This will return **true** or **false** depending on where the element is.

However this will **always return false**:

```
   function whereAreWe(myself,range){
        var parent = myself.parent();
        var position = parent.is(':even');
        alert(position);
        //outputs false
   }

   $('.hasSVG').on('click', function(){
        whereAreWe($(this),2);
   });
```

I have the working example here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hutber/kTFrF/)

In the example you will see that i am trying to see if the parent(.line) of said element is either odd or even.

Comment: `$("#map183").parent().is(':even');` seems to always be returning true

Comment: ye, thats expected. Sorry if its not clear from this. The problem is with line 5: ` var position = parent.is(':even');` It should already return false because the elements aren't moving. map183's parent does not move :)

Comment: You've got problem on parent selector. [When tested with](http://jsfiddle.net/HhNjg/) `each`, it returns `0`

Comment: Arrg, jsfiddle doesn't work properly on Chrome on Ubuntu. It's messed up. Cursor doesn't show, bunch of duplicated icons...Wish people used JSBin more.

Comment: @elclanrs ha, sorry can't help you there then.

Comment: @Barlas odd, it returns 1 `alert(parent.length)` - edit - Humm each does give nothing... - would each on a selector return anything? its just an object?

Comment: @elclanrs you may have to clear your cache to get it to start working properly again.  jsfiddle has been updating a lot (seemingly) and been slow a lot lately, so just keep refreshing and stuff, or using incognito and it should start working for you again.  Shame too, because I like it so much better than jsbin, but it's hard to use when it has these problems sometimes

Comment: @JamieHutber `each` returns all the elements in the definiton but it returns `1` element so you've definetly got problem on parent variable, it should be select clicked object's all parent elements.

Comment: I tried with `:nth-child(even)` and seems to have different results, but not correct, try and see what happens...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the :even selector is only useful within a list
but parent refers to exactly one object.
Therefore, :even with a list of 1 does not make sense.

However, you have IDs that indicate the line-number

```
var position = parent.attr("id").substr(4) % 2 == 0;
console.log(position);
```

extracting the id and deleting the "line"-string from "lineX" gives you the line-number X.
A check with MOD 2 (or alternatively a bitwise AND with 1:)

```
var position = ((parent.attr("id").substr(4) & 1) == 1);
```

will do the trick.

Comment: great way of doing this, I agree. So thanks. But why will  `$("#map183").parent().is(':even');` return its respective true or false. If you're correct then I don't understand how this works correctly.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but I think `:even` does not make any sense with `.is()`.
Is makes sense in other cases like `.is(":visible")`

[see](http://jsfiddle.net/q74kJ/1/)

`:even` makes sense on operations with multiple items:
`$("ol li:even").remove();`
This removes all even list items